# Using text shadow with animated gradient

Tags: css

So, i am trying to add a white text shadow/outline to my animated gradient but whenever i do, the text goes full white and the gradient doesn't apply.

If anyone could help me out here then that would be much appreciated

Gradient Code:

```
.linear-wipe {

  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00008B 15%, red 35%, red 50%, #00008B 70%);
  background-size: 200% auto;

  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

  animation: shine 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes shine {
    to {
      background-position: 200% center;
    }
  }
```

Shadow/Outline Code:

```
text-shadow: 
-0.2px 0px 1px white, 
0px 0.2px 1px white, 
0.2px 0px 1px white, 
0px -0.2px 1px white;
```

You can see the problem here. If you remove the "text-shadow" bit, the gradient works fine, but with it, the text just goes white:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wQvexd

Comment: use `-webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;` for outline

Comment: This worked at first, until I changed the font to a custom one. Once I did that, the outline was stuck at a certain number of pixels that was too thick for my liking. 
Thanks for the reply though :)

Answer (score 0):

use `after` psuedo element if you want to set the `text-shadow` for a gradient text;

Here I have tried something

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
}
.linear-wipe {

  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00008B 15%, red 35%, red 50%, #00008B 70%);
  background-size: 200% auto;
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position:absolute;
  animation: shine 5s linear infinite;
}

.linear-wipe:after {
  background: none;
  content: attr(data-text);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 
    -0.2px 0px 1px white, 
    0px 0.2px 1px white, 
    0.2px 0px 1px white, 
    0px -0.2px 1px white;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
@keyframes shine {
  to {
    background-position: 200% center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="linear-wipe" data-text="Hello World">Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are missing `position:relative`

Comment: inside `.linear-wipe`